# xcode 5: Custom Project Template:How to add Documentation target?

Tags: ios7, xcode5, project-template

I would like to add Documentation target to .xctemplate for custom xcode project template. What key-value pair should one add to templateInfo.plist in order to get Documentation target in place ?

Answer (score 0):

Able to solve this problem by adding a dictionary under **Targets** key in TemplateInfo.plist as:
[image]

Hope this should help to anyone looking for a similar thing.